# How to efficiently initialize parts of an array with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to figure out if I can use numpy to efficiently set a region of a 3 dimensional array to a value.  My array is a black image with 3 color channels and I want to set a region around a set of pixels in the image to a certain color.

My working, but slow, code is something like this (extracted relevant portions):

```
import skimage
import numpy as np

def clamp(n, upper, lower=0):
    return max(lower, min(n, upper))

def apply_contours(image, contours, color=(128.0,128.0,128.0), radius=5):
    """Draw the pixels in the contours in a given colour and size
    """
    for contour in contours:
        for pixel in contour:
            r1 = clamp(int(pixel[0])-radius, image.shape[0])
            r2 = clamp(int(pixel[0])+radius, image.shape[0])
            c1 = clamp(int(pixel[1])-radius, image.shape[1])
            c2 = clamp(int(pixel[1])+radius, image.shape[1])
            for y in range(r1,r2):
                for x in range(c1,c2):
                    for c in range(3):
                        image[y][x][c] = color[c]
    return image

input = skimage.io.imread("image.png")
contours = skimage.measure.find_contours(input, 0.5)
mask = np.zeros((input.shape[0],input.shape[1],3), dtype=np.uint8)
apply_contours(mask)
```

I've not used numpy much but it occurred to me that I should be able speed this up by replacing the nested loop in `apply_contours` with something like this:

```
image[r1:r2][c1:c2] = np.array([color[0],color[1],color[2])
```

but this doesn't seem to work as the resulting image does show any change, where as with the loop version it shows what I'm expecting.

I also tried:

```
image[r1:r2][c1:c2][0] = color[0]
image[r1:r2][c1:c2][1] = color[1]
image[r1:r2][c1:c2][2] = color[2]
```

but this gives me an error `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do more efficiently with numpy?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, my total n00b status with numpy.  The correct syntax is:

```
image[r1:r2,c1:c2] = np.array([color[0],color[1],color[2])
```